# Why can I only initialize a JavaFX HTMLEditor in the application start call?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, html-editor

If i place this code

```
new HTMLEditor();
```

anywhere but in my Application.start(Stage stage) implementation, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass Failed to load skin 'StringProperty [bean: HTMLEditor[id=null], name: skinClassName, value: com.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin.HTMLEditorSkin]' for control HTMLEditor[id=null]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:400)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:293)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:201)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:110)
    at javafx.scene.control.PopupControl.<init>(PopupControl.java:98)
    at javafx.scene.control.Tooltip.<init>(Tooltip.java:143)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin.HTMLEditorSkin.addButton(HTMLEditorSkin.java:785)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin.HTMLEditorSkin.populateToolbars(HTMLEditorSkin.java:470)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin.HTMLEditorSkin.<init>(HTMLEditorSkin.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:1044)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.access$500(Control.java:70)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.invalidated(Control.java:972)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.set(Control.java:964)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:76)
    at javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor.<init>(HTMLEditor.java:29)
    at com.vasolsim.tclient.TeacherClient.initHTMLEditor(TeacherClient.java:134)
    at com.vasolsim.tclient.element.form.QuestionInitNode.redrawNode(QuestionInitNode.java:53)
    at com.vasolsim.tclient.element.form.QuestionInitNode.<init>(QuestionInitNode.java:33)
    at com.vasolsim.tclient.TeacherClient.initializeStaticAssets(TeacherClient.java:172)
    at com.vasolsim.tclient.TeacherClient.main(TeacherClient.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

When I create the object in my start method everything works fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
-Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be on an FX Application thread (which is created when you launch an `Application`) in order to initialize an FX object.

If you need to initialize such an object during runtime, outside of your `Application` code, you can wrap the code in a `Platform.runLater()` call.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // add your init here
    }
});
```

This will schedule your task to be run on the FX application thread the next time it executes (actually, at some unspecified time in the future...). [See reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: Looks like my static references came back to haunt me. So if I launch in Platform.runlater(), can I assume the initialization will take place as soon as the Application starts? Thank you for the concise and quick answer! It is much appreciated.

Comment: @guyfleeman You can't assume anything, because the time of exact execution is unspecified, though the Runnable's are scheduled in the order they are posted, so you should be able to count on the order being preserved. If you are concerned with the initialization of this object being done before any subsequent operations, I might suggest the use of a `Service` which can be set up to report on success, so that you can continue with your program. A service is a more complex method to do what `Platform.runLater()` does.